# Set Value of Variable on first instance of function running

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

For example I have a variable which should increment every time the function is run. I want the variable to initially be given the value of 0, but then increase by 1 every time the function is called. I do not want to give the variable global scope, however obviously if I declare it within the function it is going to be reset to 0 every time it is called.
Is there a simple and efficient way to to do this in Javascript?

My Javascript:

```js
function myFunction(){
 var i=0;
 //Body of function
 i++;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the value on the function object itself, like this

```
function myFunction() {
    myFunction.i = myFunction.i || 0;
    myFunction.i++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use closure, like this

```
var myFunction = (function () {
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        // `myFunction` will be this function only and it increments the 
        // `i` from the enclosed function.
        i++;
    }
})();
```